# exc_bad_access using WKInterfaceSlider

Tags: swift, watchkit

I can't use WKInterfaceSlider without having exc_bad_access error.

I'm using this code:

```
@IBAction func sliderChanged(value:AnyObject) {

    println(value)

}
```

Sometimes it works for the first click on +/-

**Update**:
WKInterfaceSlider works using Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [XCode 6.2 Beta release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.2_beta_auk9ez/xcode_6.2_beta__release_notes.pdf): "Known Issues - XCode Interface Builder"

"After creating IB Actions in Swift for WKInterfaceSwitch or WKInterfaceSlider objects,
storyboards fail to compile with an error such as "Argument to 'IBAction' method cannot have
non-object type." (19003052"

Solution: remove "@IBAction" annotation (which implies @objc). Should still work ok.

Comment: Thanks. 'func sliderChanged(value:Float)' worked for me. Where i read the issue, they suggest to substitute **Float** with **AnyObject** but this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I had `@IBAction` commented out due to this, but in Beta 3 it looks OK now.